# In basic Node/Express, is there a way to treat a JSON file as a RESTful resource?

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, rest, express

I basically have a JSON file which contains an array of 100 objects, each representing a person. I need to treat this JSON file (and this array) as a resource from which I can retrieve ten person objects at a time. Is there a simple way to parse a request such that Node/Express returns to me ten objects of the array at a time based on parameters I send? Here's what a sample request might look like:

/api/people?limit=10&offset=10

Limit is the number of results to return at once.
Offset is the array index from which the returned results should begin.

The above request would return 10 person objects, beginning with the 10th index of the people array.

Basically, what I need to know is how to parse the JSON file and return the desired data from Node/Express without assistance from any other packages/tools.

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what code you've tried thus far to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple sample Express solution for this.

```
// WARNING: No error checking etc. This is very basic code. 
// This code is not production-ready. For demonstration purposes only.

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var people = require('./path/to/json/file.json');

// Consider checking that people is an array and other validation checks.

app.get('/api/people', function (req, res) {
    var offset = parseInt(req.query.offset, 10);
    var limit = parseInt(req.query.limit, 10);

    // Consider adding validation for user input here. Maybe you don't want to
    // allow them to select more than 10 items, for example.

    // NOTE: slice() uses zero-based index. Subtract one from user input if
    // first item, from user perspective, is item number 1.
    res.json(people.slice(offset, offset+limit));
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

Comment: You can just require json files no need to use `readFileSync` and `JSON.parse` on it

Comment: Good point, although note that you need to make sure your JSON file has a `.json` extension for this to work. Otherwise, you get an empty object. I've updated the answer to reflect this simpler approach.

Answer (score -1):

Use `JSON.parse(fileTxt)` to convert the file content to a javascript object. Then use `array.slice()` with the specified begin and end indexes of the array.

Comment: Small typo: I'm pretty sure you mean `slice()` rather than `splice()` as `splice()` mutates the original array which is probably not desirable in this case.